# Using VisualStudio+ Python -- how to handle "overriding stdlib module" Pylance(reportShadowedImports) warning?

Tags: python, visual-studio, conda, pylance

When running ipynbs in VS Code, I've started noticing Pylance warnings on standard library imports. I am using a conda virtual environment, and I believe the warning is related to that. An example using the glob library reads:

`"env\Lib\glob.py" is overriding the stdlib "glob" modulePylance(reportShadowedImports)`

So far my notebooks run as expected, but I am curious if this warning is indicative of poor layout or is just stating the obvious more of an "FYI you are not using the base install of python".

I have turned off linting and the problem stills persists. And almost nothing returns from my searches of the error "reportShadowedImports".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The reason you find nothing by searching is because this check has just been implemented recently (see [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/pull/4132)). I ran into the same problem as you because `code.py` from Micropython/Circuitpython also overrides the module "code" in stdlib.

The solution is simple, though you then loose out on this specific check. Just add `reportShadowedImports` to your [pyright config](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportShadowedImports). For VS Code, that would be adding it to `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  [...]
  "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
      "reportShadowedImports": "none"
  },
  [...]
}
```

Comment: This seems to conflict with the idea of a conda env.  It seems like when I'm using a conda env and its packages, then there should be no errors reported.  Is there a way to make pylance consider stdlibs to be those in the conda env being used?

Comment: By the way to found the settings.json file, search these locations:
» Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json </br> » macOS:  $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json </br> » Linux: $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: An easier solution is to rename your `code.py` to `main.py` so that it doesn't conflict. It will still be loaded on boot. Disabling all override warnings has the unwanted side-effect of removing useful warnings.

Comment: @Stefan: Your comment seems to me to be the better solution. Thanks. Maybe you set it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 8):

If your filename has the same name as a stdlib python module - for example "datetime.py" - it's gonna have this problem.

It is good practice to avoid naming files the same names as stdlib modules, so that case, the best action is to choose a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Open the User settings in VSCode:

- Open the command palette (either with F1 or Ctrl+Shift+P)
- Type "open settings"
- You are presented with a few options¹, choose Open User Settings (JSON)

[image]

This error may be due to a recognition error caused by python created by `venv` being located in the workspace folder.

Please note if your `venv` is in your project folder just exclude it with below settings (or replace `venv` with whatever is your virtual environment name).

`settings.json`

```json
"python.analysis.exclude": ["venv"]
```