# How to configure VSCode with pylance so that I can change conda environments?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda, pylance

When I use VSCode with pylance, if I change conda environments I get the

> overriding the stdlib module ... Pylance (reportShadowedImports)

warning.

There are lots of posts about this (e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5191).  Most of which suggest disabling the "reportShadowedImports":

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportShadowedImports": "none"
```

Is there a way to configure VSCode with pylance so I can switch conda environments, not disable "reportShadowedImports", and not get the "overriding the stdlib module...Pylance (reportShadowedImports)" warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I found a comment in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660176/using-visualstudio-python-how-to-handle-overriding-stdlib-module-pylancer).

You could rename your `code.py` to `main.py` so that it doesn't conflict. It will still be loaded on boot.